# How to get start and end date of months of a given range of date in php

Tags: php, datetime, date

I am using following codes to display start and end dates of current month.

```
function firstOfMonth() {
return date("m/d/Y", strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'));
}

function lastOfMonth() {
return date("m/d/Y", strtotime('-1 second',strtotime('+1 month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'))));
}

$date_start = firstOfMonth();
$date_end  = lastOfMonth();
echo $date_start;
echo $date_end;
```

**Question:** How to get start and end dates of all months in a range of date given

For Eg:

```
function daterange($startdate,$enddate)
{
...
...
...
}
```

Expected result be array of start and end dates of each month between date range of `$startdate` and `$enddate`.

Help me how to do this....

Comment: What have you tried? Is there something specific that's giving you trouble?

Comment: You know `date`. You know `strtotime`. And there must be hundreds of questions asking how to get dateranges with PHP already. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
//Function to return out start and end dates of all months in a date range given

function rent_range($start_date, $end_date)
{
    $start_date = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($start_date));
    $end_date   = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($end_date));
    $start = strtotime($start_date);
    $end = strtotime($end_date);

    $month = $start;
    $months[] = date('Y-m', $start);
    while($month < $end) {
      $month = strtotime("+1 month", $month);
      $months[] = date('Y-m', $month);
    }

    foreach($months as $mon)
    {
        $mon_arr = explode( "-", $mon);
        $y = $mon_arr[0];
        $m = $mon_arr[1];
        $start_dates_arr[] = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($m.'/01/'.$y.' 00:00:00'));
        $end_dates_arr[] = date("m/d/Y", strtotime('-1 minute', strtotime('+1 month',strtotime($m.'/01/'.$y.' 00:00:00'))));
    }

    //to remove first month in start date and add our start date as first date
    array_shift($start_dates_arr);
    array_pop($start_dates_arr);
    array_unshift($start_dates_arr, $start_date);

    //To remove last month in end date and add our end date as last date
    array_pop($end_dates_arr);
    array_pop($end_dates_arr);
    array_push($end_dates_arr, $end_date);

    $result['start_dates'] = $start_dates_arr;
    $result['end_dates'] = $end_dates_arr;
    return $result;
}

$start_date = '2011-07-29';
$end_date = '2012-03-31';
$res = rent_range($start_date, $end_date);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**My Above Function will give the month range display of dates within a given range.
This function would be useful for monthly rent calculation as indian tradition.**

**It may help some one else....**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [date function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and scroll to format character `t` which gives you the number of days. Start date will always be 1 :-)

Doing this in a loop for the number of months between the two dates and storing the values in an array is up to you

Answer (score 0):

```
function firstAndLast($d=''){
    $d = $d?$d:time();
    $f = mktime(0,0,0,date("n",$d),1,date("Y",$d));
    $l = mktime(0,0,0,date("n",$d),date("t",$d),date("Y",$d));
    return array($f,$l);
}

list($first,$last) = firstAndLast();
echo date("d/m/Y",$first)." ($first) - ".date("d/m/Y",$last)." ($last)";
```

You can pass a timestamp to the function or leave it blank and it will pick up the current time